# How to start nodes randomly

Tags: omnet++

I'm using Castalia and my topology has only two nodes (node 0 and node 1). I need to make node 0 boot in a time between 0 to 91 randomly.
I tried to use the function `SN.node[1].startupRandomizations = 91` however this function only adds a delay and not a drawing of the value.
I looked for something like that in the Castalia and Omnet manual but I couldn't find it. Could you suggest me a solution?

Answer (score 0):

The correct parameter name is `SN.node[0].startupRandomization` (without the `s` at the end). Also note that you used node index 1 in your example above, while you say you want node 0.

I am not sure what you mean by "only adds a delay and not a drawing of the value". If you set this parameter to 91 it will draw a random value in the interval [0-91] and added it to any startupOffset the node already has. This will indeed randomise the startup time the way you want it.